# Stretch Items in an ItemsControl in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

**SOLUTION**

The shortest Code to archieve the desired result was for me:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GeneralBoolSettings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{Binding IsOn, Mode=TwoWay}" OffContent="{Binding OffContent}" OnContent="{Binding OnContent}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm having trouble with something as easy as stretching the Items of an `ItemControl` horizontally. As I'm working with XAML, I dont have things like `SharedSizeGroup`as in WPF.

The solutioon presented here: [Horizontally Stretch Content in an ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076236/horizontally-stretch-content-in-an-itemscontrol) does unfortunately not work for me.
My Code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GeneralBoolSettings}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{Binding IsOn, Mode=TwoWay}" OffContent="{Binding OffContent}" OnContent="{Binding OnContent}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Some Screenshots from the Designer:

ItemControl has the correct (stretched) Size
[image: ItemControl has correct Size]

DataTemplate is already too small
[image]

I would like to avoid binding to a parent width; in my previous attempts, the width was sometimes (re-)set to 0, and I would have had to remove the binding and add it again. Also: Please no code and / or event catcher, there must be an elegant solution to this rather basic problem!

Honestly, I'm a bit surprised I can't get this to work. Mabye you can recommend a good book / website to learn a systematic approach of the basics of XAML (while we're at it)?

Comment: Hey, I have a couple random suggestions that you might find useful in your daily coding life.

Comment: First. INotifyPropertyChanged bindings automatically marshall updates onto the UI thread as of .net 3.5 (or possibly 4.0, not sure), so if your vms implement INPC and you build with that or a later version, you can update view models from whatever thread you like.

Comment: Second.  If that isn't possible, you can use the SynchronizationContext pattern to let outside agents inject thread-management logic into your view models.  It's a pattern generalized to the entire framework, not just UI parts of the framework.  You can inject the DispatcherSynchronizationContext into your view models, thereby ensuring updates are marshalled onto the UI thread, but without the stink of injecting UI dependencies into your view models.

Comment: Your question was definitely salvageable, and if you want to undelete, @ me here and I'll give it an edit to bring it within acceptable guidelines.

Comment: @Will Thanks for your help! I've undeleted my question. Your pattern sounds very promising!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to set the horizontal alignment of each item container to stretch using ItemContainerStyle property of ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GeneralBoolSettings}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleSwitch IsOn="{Binding IsOn, Mode=TwoWay}" OffContent="{Binding OffContent}" OnContent="{Binding OnContent}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```